# Cannot send saved MSG file with Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

We have a weird behaviour with Outlook 2013.
Here is how to reproduce it :

- Create a new mail from Outlook 2013 (use HTML format)
- Enter some text
- Close the mail and answer Yes when Outlook prompts you to save it : it should appear in the draft folder
- From the draft folder, drag and drop the mail to your hard drive
- Open the MSG file from your hard drive
- Send the mail

Result : when the recipient receives the mail, its body is empty!

This used to work fine with previous Outlook versions.
I tried disabling all plugins and addins, to no effect.
Using plain text format seems to help but we need to be able to use HTML.

If someone has any idea on how to solve this, thanks for sharing!

Additional information : 
The mail is completely empty for all recipients, and if you look in to the "Sent mails" folder in Outlook, you'll find the mail empy here as well.

This could be related to a recent update on Outlook 2013 (I suspect kb3055012).

Thanks!

**Update:** this seems to be a known issue : 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/problem-with-windows-update-kb3055012-and-email/85f90120-5e10-489e-a670-da399b5732be

Nothing to do, except wait fo a fix. So I guess we can close the question!

Comment: Does the email appear blank to all recipients or just a single recipient? Have you tried sending it to yourself to see if you can see the email?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question (the email appears blank to everyone).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/problem-with-windows-update-kb3055012-and-email/85f90120-5e10-489e-a670-da399b5732be

The update KB3055012 broke something, hopefully a fix will be available soon.